# Partial sums over series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like

```
       A      B
0     1.2     1
1     1.2     6
2     1.2     4
3     2.3     2
4     2.3     5
5     1.2     7
```

and I would like to obtain the partial sums for a group that shares the same value of `A` but only if they are next to each other. For this case, I would expect another `DataFrame` as in

```
0    1.2    11
3    2.3    7
5    1.2    7
```

I have a feeling that I can use `.groupby` but I can only manage it to work disregarding if the groups of `A` are next to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by helper `Series` with aggregate `first` and `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg({'A':'first','B':'sum'})
print (df)
     A   B
0  1.2  11
1  2.3   7
2  1.2   7
```

**Detail**:

Compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)d column with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups `Series`:

```
print (df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Thank you @user2285236 for comment:

> Checking for equality may lead to unwanted results when the dtype is float. np.isclose might be a better option here

```
df = df.groupby(np.cumsum(~np.isclose(df.A, df.A.shift())), as_index=False).agg({'A':'first','B':'sum'})
print (df)
     A   B
0  1.2  11
1  2.3   7
2  1.2   7

print (np.cumsum(~np.isclose(df.A, df.A.shift())))
[1 1 1 2 2 3]
```

Comment: Checking for equality may lead to unwanted results when the dtype is float. `np.isclose` might be a better option here.

Comment: Couldn't you avoid `np.isclose` by converting `df.A` to Categorical?

Comment: @jpp - In my opinion it should working nice if small number of unique values of `A` column.

Answer (score 2):

### `itertools.groupby`

Suffers from same problem highlighted by [@user2285236](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592401/partial-sums-over-series-in-pandas/50592649#comment88194373_50592420)

```
g = groupby(df.itertuples(index=False), key=lambda x: x.A)
pd.DataFrame(
    [[a, sum(t.B for t in b)] for a, b in g],
    columns=df.columns
)

     A   B
0  1.2  11
1  2.3   7
2  1.2   7
```